# Consulta web metodo em Asp.Net

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net

Estou fazendo uma consulta para plotar os dados no grafico Highchart, com intervalo de até 1h a consulta está ok, mas de 1h já fica lento para gerar o grafico.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SENSORES()
{
   aqui eu retorno a consulta do banco de dados
}

//Código usado no javascript
Dados = <%=SENSORES()%>;

//Informação de 20 registro
Dados = [[1611309619,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76],[1611309618,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76],[1611309617,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76],[1611309616,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76],[1611309615,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76],[1611309614,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76,41.76],[1611309613,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309612,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309611,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309610,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309609,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309608,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309607,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309606,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309605,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68],[1611309604,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68],[1611309603,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68,55.68],[1611309602,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309601,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8,34.8],[1611309600,27.84,27.84,27.84,27.84,27.84,27.84,27.84,27.84,27.84]];


//AQUI ELE GERAR O GRAFICO
series: [{
  type: 'line',
  name: 'PSI',
  data: (function () {

                    var data = [];
                    Dados.forEach(function (val) {
                        data.push([(val[0] * 1000), val[3]]);
                    });
                    
                    return data;
    })()

}]
```

O problema está quando eu faço uma consulta de 12h, como vai vir muito registro. Acaba demorando muito.
Como solucionar esse desafio?

Comment: como resolver? se tem muitos registros pode agrupar, se não puder, pode tentar paginar os resultados

Comment: como fazer esse procedimento?

Comment: A demora é pela consulta ou pelo tráfego do volume de dados mesmo? Está com compressão ativada e cache para esses dados?

Comment: A consulta SQL dentro do public static string SENSORES() está rápida. A Demora está sendo na variavel Dados que fica do lado do cliente. Uma consulta com intervalo de 1h não demora para gerar o gráfico, já uma consulta de 12h demora mais de 2 minutos para gerar o grafico